# How can I redraw the Timeline with new data after every click in Timeline Highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have data like this:

```
var data = [{
    x: Date.UTC(1951, 5, 22),
    name: 'First dogs in space',
    label: 'fds',
    dataLabels: {
        allowOverlap: false,
        format: '<span style="color:{point.color}">● </span><span style="font-weight: bold;" > ' +
            '</span><br/>{point.label}'
    },
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1957, 9, 4),
    name: 'First artificial satellite',
    label: 'First artificial satellite',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1959, 0, 4),
    name: 'First artificial satellite to reach the Moon',
    label: 'First artificial satellite to reach the Moon',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1961, 3, 12),
    name: 'First human spaceflight',
    label: 'First human spaceflight',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1966, 1, 3),
    name: 'First soft landing on the Moon',
    label: 'First soft landing on the Moon',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1969, 6, 20),
    name: 'First human on the Moon',
    label: 'First human on the Moon',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1971, 3, 19),
    name: 'First space station',
    label: 'First space station',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1971, 11, 2),
    name: 'First soft Mars landing',
    label: 'First soft Mars landing',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1976, 3, 17),
    name: 'Closest flyby of the Sun',
    label: 'Closest flyby of the Sun',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1978, 11, 4),
    name: 'First orbital exploration of Venus',
    label: 'First orbital exploration of Venus',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1986, 1, 19),
    name: 'First inhabited space station',
    label: 'First inhabited space station',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1989, 7, 8),
    name: 'First astrometric satellite',
    label: 'First astrometric satellite',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1998, 10, 20),
    name: 'First multinational space station',
    label: 'First multinational space station',
}];
```

Here is the fiddle link for your reference:[Fidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/on19kxqe/1/)

So right now on label click, the next indexes gonna hide (removed) and currently selected indexes are the latest ones.

So what I want after every click I don't want to use `this.remove(false)` Instead of this, I want to redraw this chart with new data which already I have.

I have tried the `SetData` method instead of remove because it takes too much time of large data.

And also try to redraw the whole chart with new data but didn't work properly.

```
var unclickable = ["First artificial satellite to reach the Moon", "First soft landing on the Moon"];

var timelinechart = new Highcharts.Chart('timeline_container', {
                chart: {
                    events: {
                        redraw: function() {
                            var series = this.series[0];
                            series.points.forEach(function(p) {
                                if (p.customDataLabel && p.dataLabel.fill !== 'rgba(64,158,255,.1)') {
                                    // console.log('inisde redraw')
                                    // this.dataLabel.text.element.style.fill= '';
                                    // p.series.chart.redraw();
                                    // p.dataLabel.attr({
                                    //     fill: 'rgba(64,158,255,.1)',
                                    //     stroke:'rgb(77, 184, 234)',
                                    // });

                                }
                            });
                        },
                        load: function() {
                            var chart = this;

                            chart.series[0].points.forEach(function(point) {
                                if(!unclickable.includes(point.label)) {
                                    point.dataLabel.on('mouseover', function() {
                                    point.dataLabel.box.css({
                                        fill: 'rgba(64,158,255,.1)',
                                    });
                                    });

                                    point.dataLabel.on('mouseout', function() {
                                    point.dataLabel.box.css({
                                        fill: 'white'
                                    });
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        // load: function () {
                        //     var series = this.series[0];
                        // }
                    },
                    // zoomType: 'x',
                    type: 'timeline'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    // max: 6,
                    visible: false,
                },
                scrollbar: {
                    enabled: data.length < 10 ? false : true
                    // enabled: true
                },
                yAxis: {
                    gridLineWidth: 1,
                    title: null,
                    labels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                    },

                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },

                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },
                // colors: [
                //     '#CCC5A6',
                //     '#545454'
                // ],
                tooltip: {
                    style: {
                        width: 300
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            mouseOver: function() {
                                // var unclickable = ["Abandoned","Appeal","Interview","RCE","Application Filed"];
                                if(unclickable.includes(this.label)) {
                                    this.dataLabel.element.style.setProperty('cursor', 'default');
                                    // this.dataLabel.element.style.setProperty('')
                                    this.dataLabel.text.element.style.setProperty('cursor', 'default');
                                    // this.dataLabel.text.element.style.setProperty('color', '#000');
                                    // this.dataLabel.options.shadow = true
                                }
                            },
                            click: function(data) {
                                // var unclickable = ["Abandoned","Appeal","Interview","RCE","Application Filed"];
                                var points = this.series.points;
                                vm.first_load = false;
                                if(!unclickable.includes(this.label)){
                                    // vm.is_timeline_wzaiting = true;
                                    vm.is_timeline_clicked = true;

                                    for (var i = points.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                        if (i !== this.index) {
                                            if (points[i]) {
                                                points[i].dataLabel.attr({
                                                    fill: '#fff'
                                                });
                                                points[i].dataLabel.text.element.style.fill= '';
                                                points[i].customDataLabel = false;
                                                points[i].remove(false);
                                                this.series.chart.redraw();
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            vm.is_timeline_waiting = false;
                                            i = -1;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    // let sliced_data =  points.slice(0,this.index+1);
                                    // console.log(this.series.chart.series[0])
                                    // console.log(this.series)
                                    // if(sliced_data){
                                        // this.series.setData(sliced_data);
                                        // this.series.chart.redraw();
                                    // }
                                    // vm.generateTimeline(sliced_data);
                                    // console.log(points.slice(0,this.index+1));
                                    this.series.chart.redraw();
                                    this.customDataLabel = true;
                                    this.series.chart.highlightedLabelIndex = this.index;
                                    // console.log(this.dataLabel)
                                    this.dataLabel.attr({
                                        fill: 'rgba(64,158,255,.1)',
                                        stroke:'rgb(77, 184, 234)'
                                    });
                                    // console.log(this.customDataLabel)
                                    this.dataLabel.text.element.style.fill= '#4db8ea';
                                    // console.log('here');
                                    // console.log(this.dataLabel.text.element);
                                    vm.GetinfoToCorrespondingTimeline(data.point.index,data.point.label);
                                    // this.dataLabel.text.element.style.fill= '';
                                }

                            },
                        },
                    },

                    dataLabels: {
                        allowOverlap: true,
                        format: '<span>● </span><span> ' +
                            '{point.x:%d %b %Y}</span><br/><span style="font-weight: bold;">{point.label}</span>'
                    },
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'circle'
                    },
                    data: data.slice(),

                }]
            },
            function() {
                const min = Math.max(this.series[0].points.length - 6, 0);
                // console.log(this.series[0].points)
                const max = Math.max(this.series[0].points.length - 1, 0);
                this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(this.series[0].points[min].x, this.series[0].points[max].x);
                this.series[0].points[this.series[0].points.length -1].dataLabel.attr({
                    fill: 'rgba(64,158,255,.1)',
                    stroke:'rgb(77, 184, 234)'
                });
                this.series[0].points[this.series[0].points.length -1].dataLabel.text.element.style.fill= '#4db8ea';
                if(this.series[0].points.length -1 && vm.first_load){
                    this.series[0].points[this.series[0].points.length -1].dataLabel.text.element.style.fill= '#4db8ea';
                    vm.first_load = false;
                }
            }
            );
```

Comment: Hi @vikash, `setData` method seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yxnmdafj/

Comment: Hi, @ppotaczek I have updated my code so that you can understand my problem exactly. In which when I removed else statement and this.remove(false) after that when I'm using setData it's not worked for me.

Comment: Could you reproduce that exact case in jsfiddle?